# Single view app (xamarin studio) equivalent in Visual Studio with xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

**Backstory**

I am currently in a course for learning how to create cross platform apps with xamarin. the first step is they have you open xamarin studios but I when I went to do that my research found that xamarin studio was being replaced by Visual Studio With Xamarin. So thats what I downloaded.

**Which leads me to my question**
In the course they have me create a new solution, so I do and then they have you select what kind of app you are building. They have you select "single view app" under the cross platform section. In Visual Studio with Xamarin instead of cross platform theres a section labeled 'multi platform' so I'm assuming thats the same thing. But theres no "Single view app" in the menu. Theres the following options.

- Blank forms app
- forms app
- native app
- blank native app
- sprite kit game
- scene kit game

***The main question***
does anyone know the visual studio with xamarin equivalent for a single view app?

Answer (score 0):

if you want ios native app so click on native select ios in single view app